# How to eliminate variables of a data that has 50% of the obs. with NA?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a data with 400 variables, and a 54822 obs. Some variables have the 50% of their obs. with NA.  I want to eliminate those variables.

With the following code, I look for the number of NAs in each variable, but I don´t know how to remove them from the data.

```
na <-sapply(x, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))

nadf <- data.frame(na)

NAG <- subset(nadf,na<27411)## the 50%
```

Comment: try `x[colSums(is.na(x)) >= 0.5*nrow(x)]`

Comment: Or the slight modification: `x[colMeans(is.na(x)) < 0.5]` (and I think you have `>` where you want `<`, @akrun.

Comment: Just had to delete my response for misunderstanding the question. @Gregor has the right one!